# How to match elements of two list in R considering the order of data frames

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am working with two list of data frames in R. I want to solve a little question I have the same number of data frames in each list and each one are in the same position. The dput version of my two lists is the next:

```
list1=structure(list(a1 = structure(list(a1 = c("001", "002", "003"
), b1 = c(12, 13, 12)), .Names = c("a1", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), a2 = structure(list(a1 = c("005", 
"006", "009"), b1 = c(12, 16, 16)), .Names = c("a1", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), a3 = structure(list(a1 = c("011", 
"012", "053"), b1 = c(2, 3, 12)), .Names = c("a1", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3"))

list2=structure(list(b1 = structure(list(d1 = c("001", "002", "003"
), c1 = c("A", "B", "C")), .Names = c("d1", "c1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), b2 = structure(list(d1 = c("005", 
"006", "009"), c1 = c("D", "E", "F")), .Names = c("d1", "c1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"), b3 = structure(list(d1 = c("011", 
"012", "053"), c1 = c("G", "H", "I")), .Names = c("d1", "c1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("b1", "b2", "b3"))
```

I want to match all data frames in `list1` with their respective data frame in `list2` considering a match between the variable `a1` for elements in `list1` and the variable `d1` for elements in `list2` that are like a ID in each data frame, with this match I would add `c1` variable from each data frame allocated in `list2` to data frames in `list1`. I want to get a new list with something like this:

```
list.final

$a1

a1 b1 c1
001 12  A
002 13  B
003 12  C 

$a2

a1 b1 c1
005 12  D
006 16  E
009 16  F

$a3
a1 b1 c1
011  2  G
012  3  H
053 12  I
```

I am trying to build a function to make this match but is so complex because I only has some knowledge over individual lists and here I have to work with two lists that can have more than 20 data frames. If I could have a function I would use `llply` function from `plyr` to make the new list but I can't find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `mapply` solution:

```
list.final <- mapply(merge, list1, list2, 
                            by.x = "a1", by.y = "d1", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
list.final 
# $a1
#    a1 b1 c1
# 1 001 12  A
# 2 002 13  B
# 3 003 12  C
# 
# $a2
#    a1 b1 c1
# 1 005 12  D
# 2 006 16  E
# 3 009 16  F
# 
# $a3
#    a1 b1 c1
# 1 011  2  G
# 2 012  3  H
# 3 053 12  I
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge` looks to be the simplest solution and probably the one I would use for such a small problem. Anyways, here is a solution with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
join_function = function( df1, df2 ) {
  dt1 = data.table(l1,key="a1")
  dt2 = data.table(l2,key="d1")
  dt1[dt2,]
}
Map(join_function, list1, list2)
```

Now for an explanation. I broke the problem into comparing the elements in each list one by one. To make the comparison, I made the function `join_function`. These lines

```
dt1 = data.table(l1,key="a1")
dt2 = data.table(l2,key="d1")
```

create `data.table` objects, which might be thought of as `data.frames` with added functionality. The `key` in each `data.table` is critical for when doing joins. When `dt1` and `dt2` are to be joined, they are compared by their keys. If a row in `dt1` and a row in `dt2` have the same key, then the columns of both those rows are combined. All of that work is done in the simple code

```
dt1[dt2,]
```

OK. So that solves the problem of doing joins for two `data.frame`s. The only thing left is to do joins on each pair of data frames in the two lists. That can be done with the `Map` function. This essentially applies a function multiple times (the function provided in the first argument to `Map`. The arguments of each function call are provided in the 2nd and 3rd arguments of the `Map` call. That's probably more than you wanted, but I just figured out how to use `data.table`s and thought an explanation like this might be helpful.

Comment: `Map` is really a wrapper for `mapply`, so you've translated the "by" arguments of a table-merge into the 'key' assignment. Nice demonstration of the homology of `data.table[i, ]` and base `merge`.